# Prove that any line passing through the intersection of two bisectors is also a bisector.

Tags: geometry, area

Given an arbitrary closed shape $F$, a line, $H$, that bisects $F$ horizontally, and a line, $V$, that bisects $F$ vertically, is it true that any line that passes through the intersection of $H$ and $V$ also bisects $F$?

I know that any given line $L$ through the intersection must divide $F$ into 6 (possibly empty) regions.

It looks kinda like this:

```
 L\   V
  ┌\──┼───┐
  │ \B│ C │
  │A \│   │
H─┼───\───┼──
  │   │\ D│
  │ F │E\ │
  └───┼──\┘
      │   \
```

So I have $$A+B+C = C+E+D = D+E+F = F+A+B$$
and $$A+B = C = D+E = F.$$

I just need to prove that $A = D$ or $B = E$, but no matter how I manipulate the given equations, I can't seem to isolate $A$ and $B$ or $D$ and $E$.

I think I should be using the fact that $L$ is a straight line somehow, since the given equations could still be true even if $L$ were curved.

My idea is that, any closed shape should have a centroid, like the center of mass, such that every line that passes through it should bisect the shape. Since there can only one such centroid, it must be the intersection of any two bisectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true. Consider $A=E=2$ and $B=C=D=F=1$. It is fairly easy to construct a geometric shape with those areas.

Comment: Does this take into consideration that $L$ is a straight line?

Comment: Actually, the example you gave does not work since we have $A+B=C$. Your values give $2+1=1$.

Comment: Then perhaps I have misunderstood. I think the condition for H to bisect the shape is $A+B+C = D+E+F$. I think the condition for V to bisect the shape is $A+B+F = C+D+E$. I think the condition for L to bisect the shape is $A+E+F = B+C+D$. Why do you expect $A+B = C$? That would mean all four quarters are equal but I don't think you can prove that from the assumptions in the question.

Comment: I am sorry, you are absolutely correct. I don't know why I assumed that the quadrants would be equal.

Answer (score 0):

The lines which bisect the area of a triangle form an envelope as shown in this picture

[image]

The blue medians intersect in the centroid of the triangle, but no other lines through the centroid bisect the area of the triangle; none of the green bisectors of the area of the triangle pass through the centroid.

It is easiest to consider the horizontal green line parallel to the base.  It must be $\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ of the way down to bisect the area of the triangle, rather than two-thirds of the way down to pass through the centroid.